# How to install and import OpenJFX?

Tags: java, openjdk, javafx

I have installed **openjdk 11** and **openjfx** (using "apt get install openjfx").
Tried to use *"import javafx"* and *"import openjfx"* in the code and *javac* always says that there is no such package.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new way to work with JavaFX if you are using Java 11. This is their official web site: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

Inside is described how to:

- Install Java 11 (JRE or JDK)
- Download their JavaFX runtime from: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
- Export the path of the JavaFX runtime: `export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-11/lib`
- compile and run java application with module path to the PATH_TO_FX and the necessary modules:

  - `javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls (other javaFX modules) HelloFX.java`
  - `java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls (other javaFX modules)  HelloFX`

For more information please visit their website read https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx and also read some information on java 9 module system.

Best luck to all!